# Use dangerMode and input in same time - sweetalert

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

I using  [Sweet Alert](https://sweetalert.js.org), so before perform a dangerous action I popup the dialog box. Example.

```js
swal({
  title: "Are you sure?",
  text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
  icon: "warning",
  buttons: true,
  dangerMode: true,
})
.then((willDelete) => {
  if (willDelete) {
    swal("Poof! Your imaginary file has been deleted!", {
      icon: "success",
    });
  } else {
    swal("Your imaginary file is safe!");
  }
});
```

But user can enter any remarks if they want, is optional and not required. So it will become like this

[image]

So I modified the code like this

```js
function RequestUpload(value) {

                swal({
                    title: "Are you sure?",
                    text: "Are you sure want to request to upload?",                   
                    icon: "warning",
                    buttons: true,                   
                    dangerMode: true,
                    content: {
                        element: "input",
                        attributes: {
                            placeholder: "Any remarks?",
                            type: "text",
                        },
                    },
                })
                    .then((willDelete,input) => {
                        if (willDelete) {

                            swal(`You typed: ${input}`);
                            //Call ajax here

                            
                        }
                        else {
                            swal(`Is not delete`);
                        }
                       
                    });

            
            }
```

But I can't get the value from the input, it keep show `undefined`.

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input value is provided as the first argument. When you click cancel, click outside of the popup or press <kbd>ESC</kbd>, you'll get `null` for the value which will close the alert (ie: trigger your else). Otherwise, if you click "Ok" it will hold your input value:

```
.then((input) => {
  if (input !== null) {
    swal(`You typed: ${input}`);
    //Call ajax here
  } else {
    swal(`Is not delete`);
  }
});
```

```js
function RequestUpload(value) {
  swal({
      title: "Are you sure?",
      text: "Are you sure want to request to upload?",
      icon: "warning",
      buttons: true,
      dangerMode: true,
      content: {
        element: "input",
        attributes: {
          placeholder: "Any remarks?",
          type: "text",
        },
      },
    })
    .then((input) => {
      if (input !== null) {
        swal(`You typed: ${input}`);
        //Call ajax here
      } else {
        swal(`Is not delete`);
      }
    });
}

RequestUpload();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```